# How to add headers to my dynamic table ? javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamic

This code ask a user for a number of lines and colums, then it generates the desired table.
But I would like to add headers to my dynamic table but I could not manage it.

```
"use strict";


// Variable
let creerTableau;
const btn1 = document.getElementById("supprimer");
const btn2 = document.getElementById("modifier");


// Fonction
creerTableau = () => {
    const nombreLignes = prompt("Nombre de lignes ?");
    const nombreColonnes = prompt("Nombre de colonnes ?");

    let theader = '<table id="tableauID" border="1">\n';
    let tbody = '';


    for (var i = 0; i < nombreLignes; i++) { //lines
        tbody += '<tr>\n';

        for (var j = 0; j < nombreColonnes; j++) { //colums
   
            tbody += '<td>';
            tbody += 'Valeur ' + i + ',' + j;
            tbody += '</td>'
        }

        tbody += '<td>';
        tbody += '<button id="modifier">Modifier</button>';
        tbody += '<button id="supprimer">Supprimer</button>';
        tbody += '</td>'
        tbody += '</tr>\n';
        tbody += '</th>';
    }
    
    let tfooter = '</table>';
    document.getElementById('body-div').innerHTML = theader + tbody + tfooter;

}
// Exécution
window.onload = creerTableau();
```

How it is :
[tab now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pu8yX.png)

What I want to create :
[tab with good code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFYIv.png)

Comment: Tu devrais renommer tes variables en anglais !

Comment: Merci, je vais peut-être le faire. Ici c'est dans le cadre d'une formation et on est tous noobs, donc ce n'est pas hyper important. Mais autant prendre dès maintenant les bonnes pratiques, I guess !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"use strict";


// Variable
let creerTableau;
const btn1 = document.getElementById("supprimer");
const btn2 = document.getElementById("modifier");


// Fonction
creerTableau = () => {
    const nombreLignes = prompt("Nombre de lignes ?");
    const nombreColonnes = prompt("Nombre de colonnes ?");

    let theader = '<table id="tableauID" border="1">\n<tr>';
    let tbody = '';


    for (var i = 0; i < nombreLignes; i++) { //lines
        tbody += '<tr>\n';

        for (var j = 0; j < nombreColonnes; j++) { //colums
            if (j == 0) {
                theader += '<th>Entete'+(j+1)+'</th>';
            }
            tbody += '<td>';
            tbody += 'Valeur ' + i + ',' + j;
            tbody += '</td>'
        }

        tbody += '<td>';
        tbody += '<button id="modifier">Modifier</button>';
        tbody += '<button id="supprimer">Supprimer</button>';
        tbody += '</td>'
        tbody += '</tr>\n';
        tbody += '</th>';
    }
    theader += '<th colspan="2">Actions</th></tr>';
    
    let tfooter = '</table>';
    document.getElementById('body-div').innerHTML = theader + tbody + tfooter;

}
// Exécution
window.onload = creerTableau();
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I simply changed from j+1 to j+i so it increments automatically.

Answer (score 0):

User can dynamically input the header names.

```
"use strict";


    // Variable
    let creerTableau;
    const btn1 = document.getElementById("supprimer");
    const btn2 = document.getElementById("modifier");


    // Fonction
    creerTableau = () => {
        const nombreLignes = prompt("Nombre de lignes ?");
        const nombreColonnes = prompt("Nombre de colonnes ?");

        let theader = '<table id="tableauID" border="1">\n';
        let tbody = '';

        tbody += '<tr>\n';
        for (var i = 0; i < nombreColonnes; i++) {
            var headerName = prompt("Enter header name " + (i + 1) + " ?");
            tbody += '<th>';
            tbody += headerName;
            tbody += '</th>'
        }
        tbody += '</tr>\n';



        for (var i = 0; i < nombreLignes; i++) { //lines
            tbody += '<tr>\n';

            for (var j = 0; j < nombreColonnes; j++) { //colums

                tbody += '<td>';
                tbody += 'Valeur ' + i + ',' + j;
                tbody += '</td>'
            }

            tbody += '<td>';
            tbody += '<button id="modifier">Modifier</button>';
            tbody += '<button id="supprimer">Supprimer</button>';
            tbody += '</td>'
            tbody += '</tr>\n';

        }

        let tfooter = '</table>';
        let st = theader + tbody + tfooter;
        document.getElementById('body-div').innerHTML = st;

    }
    // Exécution
    window.onload = creerTableau();
```

Comment: Good idea but in this case the table better be small then !

Comment: Yea, the table columns shouldn't be too large